# What to do if the padding is of different length on test data in NLP?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am having a confusion right now regarding the `maxlen` in `pad_sequences()`. Currently I am doing Fake News Classification. My question is while processing the test data what is the `maxlen` is longer than the training data. Let me give you my situation.

My code snippet:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text)

text_tokenizer = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)
```

```
len(text_tokenizer) # Getting 18285
```

```
max([len(x) for x in text_tokenizer])
```

I am getting `maxlen` = 51.

```
text_tokenizer_pad = pad_sequences(text_tokenizer, maxlen=max([len(x) for x in text_tokenizer]))
```

I am doing padding based on this maxlen size which is 51.
If I see the shape of `text_tokenizer_pad`, I get `(18285, 51)`

```
text_tokenizer_pad.shape
```

This is what I did in training part.

Let me show you what I did for testing part.

```
text_test_tokenizer = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text_test)
```

As u can see I didn't `fit_on_texts()` on test data.

```
len(text_test_tokenizer) # Gives 4575
```

```
max([len(x) for x in text_test_tokenizer])
```

This gives `maxlen` as 43, which is less than 51. Fine.

Now I am padding the test data with the same length as training data i.e. 51 because it is longer than test data length and I used in `train_test_split` and in training purpose. So the columns will be 51 there while training.

```
text_test_tokenizer_pad = pad_sequences(text_test_tokenizer, maxlen=max([len(x) for x in text_tokenizer]))
```

After that I am predicting. I am 2 questions regarding all of this-

1. Am I doing this correctly, I mean the tokenize and padding part on train data and test data ?
2. What if the `maxlen` for test data is longer than training data, what value should I choose then, because `text_tokenize_pad` is the one I used in `train_test_split`

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(text_tokenizer_pad, labels, test_size = 0.2, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
```

I tried with normal constant value say choose `maxlen` as 100 for both train and test. But this is not a perfect solution. There can always be a test data longer than 100.

Comment: I don't think you can do anything about it other than clipping your test sequence to match the maxlen.

Comment: That's what I thought initially. Just fixed the length. But is that a good thing to do  ?

Comment: There is no right answer here. You can use arbitrarily high maxlen value resulting in sparse information or select relatively small maxlen value resulting in dense information. Everyone will have a different opinion on this. However, what I am sure about is, once you have chosen the maxlen value during training it can't be changed/adjusted during testing.